# Can someone help me understand the differences between the possible actions in nvme-cli sanitize?

Tags: linux, ssd, nvme

I'm planning to use [nvme-cli](https://github.com/linux-nvme/nvme-cli) to securely erase an NVMe SSD I have, using the `sanitize` command. Most examples I've seen online look something like this: `nvme sanitize /dev/nvme0n1 -a 2`, where `/dev/nvme0n1` is the NVMe you want to sanitize, and `-a` is the type of sanitize operation to use. I'm confused about the differences between these possible `a` values.

The [man page for nvme sanitize](https://review.spdk.io/gerrit/plugins/gitiles/spdk/nvme-cli/+/1ba85e5bb5ba3446228d6cbb4eb9f92a28aedf6b/Documentation/nvme-sanitize.txt) gives a description of the possible actions, but I'm not sure I understand the differences.

```
-a <action>::
--sanact=<action>::
    Sanitize Action:
    000b - Reserved
    001b - Exit Failure Mode
    010b - Start a Block Erase sanitize operation
    011b - Start an Overwrite sanitize operation
    100b - Start a Crypto Erase sanitize operation
```

Questions:

1. What are the differences between these operations (block erase sanitize operation, overwrite sanitize operation, and crypto erase sanitize operation), and which one is most secure?
2. Most examples I've seen specify an integer number as a value for the `-a` option (i.e. `-a 2` , `-a 1`, etc.) rather than the values listed in the man page (`-a 010b`, `-a 011b`, etc.) What do values 1, 2, etc. correspond to in the man pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `b` number are bit-numbers (binary notation),
so the following values are equivalent ways of saying the same
thing:

- 001b, 1, 0x01
- 010b, 2, 0x02, 0x2
- 011b, 3, 0x03, 0x3
- 100b, 4, 0x04, 0x3

The actions are described as :

- Block Erase – low level block erase on media (physically erase NAND blocks)
- Crypto Erase - change media encryption key
- Overwrite – overwrite with data patterns (not good or recommended for NAND based SSDs due to endurance)

The above information was found in the sanitize mode notes from
[NVMe Tips and Tricks ww46'18 rev2](https://web.archive.org/web/20200603205054/https://www.nvmedeveloperdays.com/English/Collaterals/Proceedings/2018/20181204_PRECON2_Hands.pdf)
by Jonmichael Hands, "Strategic Planner / Product Line Manager for Intel Data Center SSDs".

Comment: excellent resource, thanks. So it seems like sanitize's crypto erase (-a 4) is similar/equivalent to nvme-cli format -s 2 (cryptographic erase) https://manpages.debian.org/testing/nvme-cli/nvme-format.1.en.html.  As for -a 3 (overwrite), any insight in to how 'overwrite' in this context would be different than overwriting a disk with random data using something like dd  if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/nvme0n1 ?

Comment: Sorry, I have no knowledge about it.

Comment: Note that not all modes are supported by all SSDs. `nvme id-ctrl --human-readable /dev/nvme0n1 | grep -i sanitize` to see what modes are supported.